# Java incompatible types error for generic class variables

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I have a class with `List<String>` field. If I put a generic parameter for the class definition, the compilation error occurred when accessing the list.

This code is compiling successfully.

```
package com.test;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {
    public List<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass c = new TestClass();
        String name = c.strings.get(0);
    }
}
```

But this is not compiling.

```
package com.test;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass<E> {
    public List<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass c = new TestClass();
        String name = c.strings.get(0);
    }
}
```

The only change is the Generic parameter `E`. But the field clearly defined as `List<String>`. It gives

```
Error:(11, 36) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

for `String name = c.strings.get(0);`.

Though this can be resolved by, `TestClass<?> c = new TestClass();` I need to know the exact issue.

Actually my question is why Java compiler cannot identify the generic type of fields with the raw type? Why it erase the generic type of `List` which is not related to `E`? I have no question if I defiled list as `List<E>`.

Comment: The non-obvious point is that raw types remove all generics, not simply those related to the omitted type variables.

Comment: @shmosel your answer say that it is erased, but not explain why. Can you   tell me the reason for erasing?

Comment: See the section titled **If it's unsafe, why is it allowed to use a raw type?**